# what is wrong with my checkbox in span container?

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox within a span container. Using the following code, I can successfully toggle the checkbox when the span tag is click. However, it fails when the checkbox itself is clicked.

```
    $(function(){
        $("span").click(function(e){
            if ($(this).find("input[name='test']").attr('checked') == true)
            {
                $(this).find("input[name='test']").removeAttr('checked') ;
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).find("input[name='test']").attr('checked', 'checked') ;
            }
        }) ;

    }) ;
```

Why is this happening? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

```
.attr('checked') == true
```

jQuery 1.6.2 returns 'false' to this, because .attr('checked') == 'checked'

And I suggest to make a little refactoring:

```
$(function(){
    $("span").click(function(e) {
        var chk = $(this).find("input[name='test']");
        if (chk.is(':checked')) {
            chk.removeAttr('checked') ;
        }
        else {
            chk.attr('checked', 'checked') ;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not all there is to it and does not work if the checkbox itself is clicked. Try the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CcLPF/1/

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I've forgot about the propagation. And I think that it isn't correct to modify my answer now. So let it be half-wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that when the checkbox itself is clicked, the click event bubbles up to `<span>` which then negates the action. [This fiddle reproduces the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/CcLPF/1/) (clicking on the checkbox itself does not toggle its state because the function negates the default checkbox behaviour).

A quick fix would be to use [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to stop the event bubbling up when the checkbox is clicked. For example:

```
$("span").click(function(e) {
    var chk = $(this).find("input[name='test']");
    chk.prop('checked', !chk[0].checked); /* assume only 1 checkbox */
}).find("input[name='test']").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[See this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/PhasK/2/).

Alternatively, inspect the click target to see which element was clicked and only toggle the state if the checkbox itself was not clicked. E.g.

```
$("span").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.type != "checkbox") {
        var chk = $(this).find("input[name='test']");
        chk.prop('checked', !chk[0].checked);
    }
});
```

[See this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/PhasK/4/)

Note that from jquery 1.6, you should be using [`.prop(checked)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("span").click(function() {
    $("input[name='test']", this).prop('checked', $("input[name='test']",this).prop('checked') ? false: true);
});
```